# multiple datepicker material-ui out of order

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

```
          <DatePicker
            label={'Start Date'}
            date={startDate}
            handleDateTime={handleStartDate}
            width='48rem'
            showDefaultDate={startDate?.default}
            clickHandler={() => clickHandler('startDateOpen', true)}
            closeHandler={() => closeHandler('startDateOpen', false)}
            openStatus={pickerStatus.startDateOpen}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={3} className={classes.filterDateRow}>
          <DatePicker
            label={'End Date'}
            date={endDate}
            handleDateTime={handleEndDate}
            width='48rem'
            showDefaultDate={endDate?.default}
            // clickHandler={() =>
            //   clickHandler('endDateOpen', 'startDateOpen', true)
            // }
            closeHandler={() => setEndStatus(false)}
            openStatus={endStatus}
          />
        </Grid>
```

I have to Datepickers but no matter what I try, it will always make me choose a date for the end date before start date. Anyone deal with this issue before?

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence. What happen if you click the first picker?

Comment: @NearHuscarl it won't let you click on the first picker, only the second picker then it will let you select the first.

Comment: Can you put all of your code here?